# How to install SubtitleEdit on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, subtitle

I use [Subtitle Edit 3.5.9](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases) on Windows all the time, but would like to get it running on Ubuntu too. (Maybe as preparation for Windows 7 EOL).

It states for SE359.zip:

> This also works on Linux (when mono/mono-form/etc is installed)
>   Linux users should also look here: http://www.sub-talk.NET/topic/2751-subtitle-edit-for-ubuntu-troubleshoting-tips-and-tricks/

I have never used mono before and am not a so experienced Linux user.
There are mono packages in [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mono&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) but I have no idea about the best way to install or what is needed.

The referenced page [Subtitle Edit For Ubuntu - Troubleshoting, Tips And Tricks](http://www.sub-talk.net/topic/2751-subtitle-edit-for-ubuntu-troubleshoting-tips-and-tricks/)  is dated and not conclusive as far as I can tell.

So I would like to find out if there is a confirmed process to run this software, or any advice to try to get there.

Comment: There also seems to be an alternative for Linux: the package subtitleeditor is available in Xenial Xerus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Download SubtitleEdit 3.5.9](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases/download/3.5.9/SE359.zip) from their GitHub site, the portable version works best.

   ```
   wget https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases/download/3.5.9/SE359.zip
   ```
2. Download full mono package.

   ```
   sudo apt install mono-complete
   ```
3. Extract `SE359.zip`, then run `SubtitleEdit.exe`-cutable file from terminal.

   ```
   mono SubtitleEdit.exe
   ```

Subtitle Edit 3.5.9 on my 18.04

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works as advertised. The only minor issue I see it that open/save dialogs are not Unicode capable. Subtitles themselves are OK after setting the font in Options.

Comment: glad you got it working :)

Comment: Also, the display issue in the Start time and Duration boxes is fixed in Subtitle Edit 3.5.11